# Compiler warning "Missing optimization information" OnEntry and OnExit with NullGuard.PostSharp

Tags: postsharp, aop

Just installed Postsharp 2.1 from the nuget package and then installed Phil Haack's NullGuard package.

As I add the [EnsureNonNullAspect] aspect at either the class or method level I immediately get the following compiler warnings:

```
Warning 1   Missing optimization information on method'
            NullGuard.PostSharp.EnsureNonNullAspect.OnEntry(
            PostSharp.Aspects.MethodExecutionArgs)'.
            This information is computed automatically by PostSharp.
            Make sure that assembly NullGuard.PostSharp is processed by PostSharp
Warning 2   Missing optimization information on method
            'NullGuard.PostSharp.EnsureNonNullAspect.OnExit(
            PostSharp.Aspects.MethodExecutionArgs)'.
            This information is computed automatically by PostSharp.
            Make sure that assembly NullGuard.PostSharp is processed by PostSharp
```

It could be that this is nothing to worry about, but:

a) I don't like compiler warnings that I can't find the answer to anywhere on Google.

b) it could be something to worry about.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Cheers!

Tod.

Comment: updated your github issue with a response: https://github.com/Haacked/NullGuard/issues/3

Comment: So I just pulled the latest source from GitHub and I'm getting the same warnings still (just applied to OnEntry and OnSuccess as you predicted).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using the free version of PostSharp, which doesn't include the aspect optimization feature. [See the comparison of features on PostSharp.net](http://www.postsharp.net/purchase).

https://github.com/Haacked/NullGuard/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I might have found a solution. I added the following tag in the project files that were raising the warnings:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <UsePostSharp>true</UsePostSharp>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This solved the issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the library included in that NuGet package has not been processed by PostSharp.