# How to fix PostSharp warning LA0036?

Tags: .net, postsharp

When building my project I get lots of PostSharp warnings like

```
POSTSHARP: postsharp warning LA0036: Missing optimization information on method '...'.
```

What does it mean and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiler warning "Missing optimization information" OnEntry and OnExit with NullGuard.PostSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313439/compiler-warning-missing-optimization-information-onentry-and-onexit-with-null)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I might have found a solution. I added the following tag in the project files that were raising the warnings:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <UsePostSharp>true</UsePostSharp>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says itself, the project containing the aspect must be processed by PostSharp too.